# How to use "torch.roll" as a component step in "torchvision.transforms.Compose" for image augmentation

Tags: pytorch, torchvision

I want to use `torch.roll` as a image augmentation step. However, `torchvision.transforms.Compose` asks for a list of `transforms` as the inputs. While `torch.roll` is not a member of the `transforms`, I am wondering if there is a convenient way to include `torch.roll` in the input list of `torchvision.transforms.Compose`.

Instead of `torch.roll`, the `transforms` member of `RandomAffine(translate)` does a similar job. But `RandomAffine(translate)` can only do simple fills on empty edges instead of rolling fills. So I still prefer to use `torch.roll` if possible.